# Http Response Not Formatting Json Data Correctly ASP Core Web API

Tags: json, asp.net-core-webapi

Good evening I am working on a web api project in ASP Core 2.0, and I am stumped, I have a get method that takes in a data value processes it grabbing data from the database, but The json response is not closing the return data on the classMember object causing it to fail,could someone tell me what I am doing wrong.

Here is the json data I get when I hit the URL, it is not closing correctly.

```
{  
   "claimNumber":49324654,
   "companyName":"Test",
   "contactName":"Test",
   "addressOne":"4231 N 67th St",
   "addressTwo":"4231 N 67th St",
   "city":"Milwaukee",
   "state":"WI",
   "zipCode":"53216",
   "phone":"4144442222",
   "tin":"Will",
   "email":"wsmith@gmail.com",
   "name2":null,
   "name3":null,
   "companyType":null,
   "agentType":"Pharmacy Benefits Manager",
   "amountPaid":"12",
   "signature":"Test",
   "position":"Test",
   "sessionGuid":null,
   "dateCreated":"2018-04-21T12:59:16.68",
   "classMembers":[  
                    {  
                      "classMemberId":116,
                      "claimNumber":49324654,
                      "name":"Will Smith",
                      "fein":"Will Smith"
```

The code I am running is here

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetTppPharmaceuticals([FromRoute] int id)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }


        var claim = _context.TppPharmaceuticals.Include(a => a.ClassMembers).Where(x => x.ClaimNumber == id).FirstOrDefault();

        if (claim == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(claim);
    }
```

I have been working on this all day, and it just not clicking to what I am doing wrong. Ultimately I am trying to pass this json data to Angular 5 for processing, but can't get it to work before that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert the object clain em json format using the newtonsoft lib and write the result here.

Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json

Comment: Thanks @Daniel Oliveira, I figured it out.